# Is there any possible way to handle stop reactor event in Twisted framework, python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, twisted, reactor

I have to execute code, when twisted reactor stops. Is there any standart way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with [`reactor.addSystemEventTrigger`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#addSystemEventTrigger).  but you probably don't need to do it.  Please be more specific in future questions.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.